# Drush db connection issues after upgrading to MAMP 4?

Tags: database, drush, 7

Upgraded to MAMP 4 yesterday and cannot get Drush to connect for the life of me. I believe I had a similar problem with MAMP 3, but the following fixed the issue. No luck this time.

```
sudo mkdir /var/mysql
sudo ln -s /Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock /var/mysql/mysql.sock
```

Any ideas? I have Drush installed globally with Composer. Here's the error:

```
    Command pm-update needs a higher bootstrap level to run - you will   [error]
need to invoke drush from a more functional Drupal environment to run
this command.
The drush command 'pm-update' could not be executed.                 [error]
Drush was not able to start (bootstrap) the Drupal database.         [error]
Hint: This may occur when Drush is trying to:
 * bootstrap a site that has not been installed or does not have a
configured database. In this case you can select another site with a
working database setup by specifying the URI to use with the --uri
parameter on the command line. See `drush topic docs-aliases` for
details.
 * connect the database through a socket. The socket file may be
wrong or the php-cli may have no access to it in a jailed shell. See
http://drupal.org/node/1428638 for details.

Drush was attempting to connect to:
 Drupal version         :  7.50
 Site URI               :  http://default
 Database driver        :  mysql
 Database hostname      :  localhost
 Database port          :
 Database username      :  root
 Database name          :  ba_dev
 PHP executable         :  /usr/local/bin/php
 PHP configuration      :  /usr/local/etc/php/5.5/php.ini
 PHP OS                 :  Darwin
 Drush script           :  /Users/ja/.composer/vendor/drush/drush
                           /drush.php
 Drush version          :  8.1.3
 Drush temp directory   :  /tmp
 Drush configuration    :
 Drush alias files      :
 Drupal root            :  /Users/ja/Sites/ba/public_html
 Drupal Settings File   :  sites/default/settings.php
 Site path              :  sites/default
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Figured this out by adding the following to my .bash_profile file and modifying the PHP versions to match what's in MAMP. Working just fine again.

```
export PATH="/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin:/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.4.45/bin:$PATH"
export PATH="/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin:/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.5.38/bin:$PATH"
export PATH="/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin:/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.6.25/bin:$PATH"
export PATH="/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin:/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.0.10/bin:$PATH"
```

After this run:

```
source ~/.bash_profile
```

Answer (score 1):

After some hours of search, I finally found the final piece. Hope this help someone :D.

MAMP PRO on Mac
[image]